# Where can I see my perfect games in steam?

Tags: steam, achievements

In my achievement showcase there is an item which says that I have 1 perfect game (which means 100% of the achievements gathered). So I browsed my games game by game and was still unable to find that specific game. There is also no link in the showcase. After some googling I still have not found a way to find the perfect games in Steam.

So, where can I see my perfect games in Steam?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Steam does not provide such functionality. You need to use a 3rd party tool. One of such websites is [**AStats**](http://astats.astats.nl/astats/FindUser.php).

Once you've found your profile, you'll be able to navigate to the page with *games completed 100%* like in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRB0a.png).

Comment: How do you view your perfect games in AStats?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Scroll down on your profile, there is a link called "see achievement games as a list" There you can sort it by percentage.

Answer (score 4):

December 2020 answer: Steam now has a "Perfect Games" tab that you can access from your profile, e.g:

[https://steamcommunity.com/id/{username}/games](https://steamcommunity.com/id/%7Busername%7D/games)

[https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/{profile-id}/games/](https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/%7Bprofile-id%7D/games/)

[image: perfect games tab on steam profile]

Answer (score 2):

I can offer an alternative solution. Use this script:

[Steam-Zero](https://github.com/levelost/steamzero).

Comment: +1 for this "client-side" solution, it doesn't work though (or it can't deal with my 800 games lib)

Comment: This solution works with full public profile (Steam API relation). Test it on user Masafor.

Comment: What do you mean by "full public"? As far as I know I have set everything on my profile to public. steamid is "Paedow"

Comment: This works like a charm. +1

Comment: Anybody else having CORS-issues? I had to add a simple PHP-wrapper for Steam API -requests to get around the fact, that Steam API won't return CORS-headers. My changes are at https://github.com/HQJaTu/steamzero